# Exception trying to connect a websphere server

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, rmi, corba

I have a eclipse plugin that connects to the WAS via RMI ...

When I am running the plugin in eclipse, works fine ... but when I try to run on RDz(http://www-01.ibm.com/software/rational/products/developer/systemz/ is a eclipse platform build by IBM) I got the bellow exception.

```
java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY027 o receptor é incompatível com classe de declaração; class=com/ibm/rmi/corba/TypeCodeImpl, method=read_value_body(Lorg/omg/CORBA_2_3/portable/InputStream;)V, pc=233
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.CDROutputStream.<clinit>(CDROutputStream.java:1105)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ORB.<init>(ORB.java:277)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.ORB.<init>(ORB.java:187)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB.<init>(ORB.java:569)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.omg.CORBA.ORB.create_impl(ORB.java:322)
    at org.omg.CORBA.ORB.init(ORB.java:363)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.corba.CorbaUtils.getOrb(CorbaUtils.java:215)
    at com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.CNCtx.initUsingIiopUrl(CNCtx.java:332)
    at com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.CNCtx.initUsingUrl(CNCtx.java:289)
    at com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.CNCtx.initOrbAndRootContext(CNCtx.java:251)
    at com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.CNCtx.<init>(CNCtx.java:103)
    at com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.CNCtxFactory.getInitialContext(CNCtxFactory.java:61)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:695)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:318)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:253)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:227)
    at my.package.product.core.server.LPDAProxy.lookup(LPDAProxy.java:68)
    at my.package.product.core.server.session.LPDASessionProxy.open(LPDASessionProxy.java:145)
    at my.package.product.core.server.session.LPDASession.open(LPDASession.java:99)
    at my.package.product.core.server.task.OpenConnectionTask.runServerTask(OpenConnectionTask.java:94)
    at my.package.product.core.server.task.LPDAServerTask.runTask(LPDAServerTask.java:88)
    at my.package.product.core.server.LPDATask.run(LPDATask.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.ProgressMonitorDialog.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressMonitorJobsDialog.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressManager.run(Unknown Source)
    at my.package.product.core.server.LPDAServer.executeTask(LPDAServer.java:385)
    at my.package.product.core.server.LPDAServer.open(LPDAServer.java:175)
    at my.package.product.core.server.LPDAServer.checkConnection(LPDAServer.java:333)
    at my.package.product.core.server.LPDAServer.getLPDARepository(LPDAServer.java:314)
    at my.package.product.core.ui.common.selector.repository.RepositorySelector.load(RepositorySelector.java:152)
    at my.package.product.core.ui.common.selector.repository.RepositorySelector.refresh(RepositorySelector.java:131)
    at my.package.product.core.ui.common.selector.repository.RepositorySelector.access$0(RepositorySelector.java:128)
    at my.package.product.core.ui.common.selector.repository.RepositorySelector$1.widgetSelected(RepositorySelector.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1384)
```

This exception happens in the lookup method from InitialContext ... When I execute only the lookup method using the current parameters in a single class, works fine.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Can you translate that error message into English?

Comment: sorry dude ... 

"the receiver is incompatible with class declaration"

Comment: So you have different versions of that class at client and server.

Comment: It is possible. I am testing my plugin in RDz platform that comes with java 7 ... the server was running java 5. I am trying to run the RDz platform with java 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am having problem because the server is running java 5 and I am using java 7. There is some incompatibility between this versions when I try to lookup a EJB.